# Согласование слов в предложении

Tags: согласование, падежи

Вырезать, копировать, вставлять выделенный текст в документ или вырезать, копировать, вставлять выделенный текст в документЕ?

Answer (score 1):

Возможны оба варианта. Всё зависит от направления. 1. Вырезать, копировать, вставлять выделенный (где-то в другом источнике) текст в документ. 2. Вырезать, копировать, вставлять  (куда-либо) выделенный в документЕ текст.
Судя по конструкции Вашего предложения, Вы имели ввиду первый вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Выделенный текст в документе можно вырезать, копировать, вставлять в документ.

Answer (score 0):

Вряд ли можно перечислить  глаголы с разным управлением как однородные

Вырезать что? где? откуда? из чего? - Вырезать выделенный в документе текст

Копировать что? где? откуда? куда? - Копировать выделенный   в документе текст в другой документ

Вставить что? куда? во что? - вставить скопированный  текст в документ.

Возможно, конечно, вставить выделенный текст в документЕ, если из одного места документа в другое,но ведь Вы не это хотите сказать? И вообще, нужно говорить, зачем это Вам, может, кто что и подсказал бы

Answer (score 0):

Фраза построена неудачно (см. объяснение в предыдущих ответах), ее нужно перестроить, например так:

**Вырезать, копировать выделенный текст и вставлять его в документ.**

Дополнительное пояснение

При наличии слова "выделенный" просто так перечислить эти три действия через запятую нельзя. Поясню. Если они перечислены через запятую, то возможен только один из двух вариантов:

Вариант 1. Это три независимых действия:

- Вырезать выделенный текст
- Копировать выделенный текст
- Вставлять выделенный текст

Этот вариант нелогичен, так как действие "вставлять выделенный текст" не является независимым, и именно из-за того, что речь идет не об абстрактном тексте, (о котором можно было бы предположить, что он уже находится в оперативной памяти и его можно вставить в документ за один шаг), а о **выделенном**. То есть перед  вами документ, в нем - выделенный текст, и прежде чем **вставить** его в тот или другой документ вы должны его **вырезать** или **скопировать**.

Вариант 2. Это три последовательных действия (вырезать, потом  скопировать, потом вставить). Опять неверно. Здесь есть "третий лишний". К цели ведет цепочка из двух действий: "вырезать -> вставить" или "скопировать -> вставить"

Однако если убрать слово "выделенный", то речь пойдет о тексте вообще и становится возможным перечислить все возможные действия с текстом через запятую как три независимых действия:

**Вырезать, копировать, вставлять текст в документ.**

При этом "в документ" относится только к "вставлять" и нет проблем с управлением, о которых говорили другие участники.

Повторюсь еще раз. Здесь просто "текст", а не "выделенный текст", поэтому можно предположить, что он уже находится в оперативной памяти и его можно **вставить** за один шаг.

Answer (score 0):

> Вырезать, копировать, вставлять выделенный текст в документ

Вырезать "в документ" не получится (только врезать))). Поэтому такой вариант вряд ли возможен в принципе.

> или вырезать, копировать, вставлять выделенный текст в документЕ?

А это в принципе-то возможно, но уж очень тяжеловесно получается. Стоит перестроить.